# Do flexible braided hoses have a shelf life if stored unused?

Tags: plumbing, hose

As far as I know, their components are the EDPM/nitrile rubber inner tube, the stainless steel fittings/crimping at either end (possibly a plastic push-fit connector) and the stainless steel braid.

Provided they are stored correctly, I suspect the stainless steel components would not be an issue, but how about the rubber tubing? Does the rubber become brittle if left unused?

Is there any point beyond which you would no longer consider them safe for use?

Answer (score 1):

Any rubber or synthetic will degrade with age it depends upon the composition at which rate that will happen. If they are old 10 years or so I would just buy new ones the risk from damage is to great.

Answer (score 1):

It highly depends on how it is stored. In full sun exposure for a year outside with temperature changing all the time, I would not reuse it. If it is stored inside in the dark I would consider it after careful inspection.